# GWT - How to add KeyDownHandler to Rootpanel

Tags: java, gwt, keyboard-events

The basic requirement is my application should be able to identify the key combination ALT + S to save any form so that the user doesnt have to use the mouse and take it all the way to 'Save' button to click to save the form.

I am trying to add KeyDownHandler to the RootPanel like this but this doesnt seem to work.

```
RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get("mainpanel");

KeyDownHandler handler = new KeyDownHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent arg0) {

        if (arg0.isAltKeyDown() && arg0.getNativeKeyCode() == 83) {
            save();
        }
    }
};

rootPanel.addDomHandler(handler, KeyDownEvent.getType());
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new Event.NativePreviewHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onPreviewNativeEvent(Event.NativePreviewEvent event) {
    if (event.getNativeEvent()
             .getType().equals("keydown")) {
      if (event.getNativeEvent().getAltKey() &&
          event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_S) {
        save();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am sorry. This is no so clear to me. To what widget are you trying to add the handler? And when does the control come to onPreviewNativeEvent() ?

Comment: Just add this code to your EntryPoint and you will receive every event which happens in your RootPanel including keydown, altkey etc.

Comment: That's awesome! It worked. Thank you so much.

However KeyCodes.KEY_S doesn't exist. KeyCodes only contains non-printable keys. I just figured out that keyCode for button 's' is 83. I just have to make sure that 83 is always 's' in all the browsers.

Comment: KeyCodes should be defined: http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/constant-values.html#com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes.KEY_S

KEY_S is defined as 83 in all Browser

Comment: I am using GWT 2.4. May be this class has been updated in one of the later versions.

Comment: This is the way to go, tested it today and it works correctly for the usecase mentioned

Answer (score 1):

Key events only work on text editors where you can press in it. Panel is a div element. You cannot key down on a div. Hence you can't.

Comment: Right. The same piece of code worked only when the focus is on any of the TextBox. Note that I am adding the KeyDownHandler to the RootPanel and not to any FocusWidget. At a minimum, I am looking for a workaround to accomplish this.

Comment: @Vadiraj did you try setting tabindex 1 to rootpanel ?

Comment: setTabIndex() API is provided in FocusWidget class. So I can't set it to any non-focusable widget like RootPanel.

Comment: @Vadiraj That is what, you cannot get it work, unless you have focus :)

Comment: I do not believe in 'It can not be done!' :)

When you are on facebook, try pressing ALT + 3 (No matter where the control or focus is), it will take you to Friend's list. I just want a similar functionality to identify the key combinations.